# Retrieving all push notifications sent to a virtual phone

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-platform, push-notification

I want to retrieve all notifications sent by a number of free apps (iOs or Android, I don't care). How would you proceed?

Ideally, this solution could be deployed on a GCP VM. I tried Android Studio on a VM but I cannot seem to launch a virtual device. There may be a simpler way.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.